# How to clean a toaster from inside?

Tags: cleaning, toaster

This is the toaster that I have. I wish to clean it from inside. It has got a kind of wire mesh inside it. What's the way out?

[image]

Comment: Where does it actually need cleaning? Is there something nasty stuck in there? Most of the time all you have to do is empty the crumb tray, and maybe let some things that've gotten caught elsewhere burn off.

Comment: @Jefromi It has dust inside it. It doesn't have a lid, so the dust has now "stuck" inside it.

Comment: After unplugging it, I guess you could see if you can manage to get a vacuum attachment down it, to vacuum out the dust. Other than that, you'll probably have to disassemble it. (Why is dust a problem? Doesn't it fall to the crumb tray, which you can normally remove and clean?)

Answer (score 8):

Just found this page when I was trying to find a solution to removing crumbs that lodged on the areas above the tray and wouldn't move when I shook the toaster upside down. I have now discovered that using a paintbrush (art not decorating) is successful.

Comment: Toothbrush works as well.

Answer (score 5):

For a start I'd hold the toaster upside down and attempt using a vacuum cleaner with a narrow nozzle attachment in combination with gentle shaking to try and dislodge the dust. Failing that compressed air is available in cans and is often used for removing dust from electronic devices and computer systems. The following is one example from Amazon although you should be able to find alternatives at a local computer or electronics retailer:

[http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Gas-Duster-10oz-Pack/dp/B004E2MF5S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E2MF5S)

Although it may be tempting to use a brush or similar to remove the dust I'd recommend against it because the heating element may have become quite brittle through constant heating and cooling cycles. Also if some of the bristles become detached during cleaning you may either leave behind toxic plastic or metal fibers that may cause a short-circuit.

It goes without saying to do it with the power cord removed for safety. A toaster will be electrically safe as soon as power has been removed, the same assumption should not be made with other appliances such as microwave ovens and TVs.

Answer (score 3):

The best way i have found to clean a toaster from the inside is to use a compressed air duster. That will make it very easy to blow out all the crumbs from the the bottom of the toaster. You can view it [here](http://amzn.to/1OXf0oa)

Comment: it's already mentioned in an answer 3 years older than yours...

Answer (score 0):

Plastic straw. Prod with it. Blow through it.

Just be sure to not lose a shred of plastic on the element.

Comment: *Whole sentences. Improves readability.*

Comment: Martin, welcome to Seasoned Advice! Pardon my little pun above, but please really keep your readers in mind. You know the SE system and know that we strive to create questions and answers that are building a knowledge-base and readable post are the first step to a valuable answer. If we take the time to answer, we might as well write well.

Answer (score -1):

i used a damp paper towel and a butter knife i just pushed the paper towel down inside the toaster and moved it back and forth and then turned it upside down and shook it and everything came out

Comment: For items that are going to heat up, it might be a better idea to use a dishcloth, washcloth, or other fabric item vs. a paper item that might tear and then you have to try to extract bit of it out of the toaster so they don't burn and set the whole thing on fire.